# Create custom bash script to theme the xubntu desktop environment

Tags: linux, shell-script, xfce, desktop-environment, theme

I want to create a bash script or python script which will help me change the whole look and feel of xubntu xfce v20.04 lts hence I wanted guidance how should I approach this .I know bash but not much I have also gone through the kali custom images links still no luck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! We probably need a more specific question to help you out. What do you intend to customize?

Comment: All the theme of xfce de and some menu of possible

Comment: Customizing "the whole look and feel" of Xfce isn't a matter of creating a bash or python script. As noted on the Xfce Wiki page [How to install new themes](https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes), there are 5 different themes you can adjust in Xfce: the window decorations, the GTK+ interfaces, the cursors, the notifications, and the icons. Of course, desktop wallpaper, panels, and choice of panel plugins can be changed as well. And accessories like a desktop system monitor, a dock, and the like can be added to further effect the look and feel.

Comment: We can create script to change the themes and hi elements right if yes then that's all I want

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar based on a youtube video about customizing xfce to look more like mac os big sur and here is an example script that I think is more or less something what you were trying to do. It downloads and changes xfce theme, icons, cursors and wallpaper to make a fresh installation of xubuntu look more like mac os:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
cd ~
mkdir .themes
cd .themes
wget https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme/raw/ceed403d404dc93895d8da4f8b8a4af82be9cf92/stable-release/Gnome-3-28/WhiteSur-light.tar.xz
tar -xf WhiteSur-light.tar.xz 
rm WhiteSur-light.tar.xz 
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s WhiteSur-light
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/theme -s WhiteSur-light
cd ~
mkdir .icons
cd .icons
wget https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-icon-theme/archive/refs/tags/2020-10-11.tar.gz
tar -xf 2020-10-11.tar.gz WhiteSur-icon-theme-2020-10-11
cd WhiteSur-icon-theme-2020-10-11
./install.sh -d $HOME/.icons
cd ~/.icons
rm 2020-10-11.tar.gz 
rm -r WhiteSur-icon-theme-2020-10-11
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/IconThemeName -s WhiteSur
wget https://github.com/vinceliuice/McMojave-cursors/archive/25120f0f3cd0fc2390fae4abbee184c524b84738.zip
unzip 25120f0f3cd0fc2390fae4abbee184c524b84738.zip
cd McMojave-cursors-25120f0f3cd0fc2390fae4abbee184c524b84738
cp -r dist ~/.icons/McMojave-cursors
cd ~/.icons
rm 25120f0f3cd0fc2390fae4abbee184c524b84738.zip
rm -r McMojave-cursors-25120f0f3cd0fc2390fae4abbee184c524b84738
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/CursorThemeName -s "McMojave-cursors"
cd ~/Pictures
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-kde/e9342d222905267245724155fdaf23ff697ddd19/wallpaper/WhiteSur.png
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -l | grep last-image | while read path; do xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p $path -s ~/Pictures/WhiteSur.png; done
```